# "Target not defined" error when trying to get target of event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to calculate triangles, and I'm trying out my code right now so I need to make an algorithm to calculate the triangles instead of having it hard-coded. I need to find grab the target of an event listener but `target` isn't working and I don't know why or how to fix it. The `target` refers to the `aV && a` before the event listener which are both input fields.

```
function calc(){
    if (target.value.length > 0){
        console.log("hooray");
    };
};

aV && a.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        calc();
    };
});
```

Comment: in `calc()` you are not passing parameter; try passing `calc(ev)` and in `calc()` definition, `function calc(event){ if(event.target.value){ .... } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That entire `addEventListener` statement is a conditional which is the equivalent of going:

```
true && true;
```

It does nothing. Add an `if` statement (also make sure you're passing `ev.target` into `calc` as an argument:

```
function calc(target){
    if (target.value.length > 0){
        console.log("hooray");
    };
};

if (aV) {
    a.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
        if(ev.keyCode == 13){
            calc(ev.target);
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a rule on when I should pass parameters through functions it really confuses me. Any links to a video I could watch or something?

Comment: Nope - just pass an argument when you need to give information to a function that would not be accessible otherwise (e.g. a local scoped variable).

Comment: Alright, well it worked perfectly and I get how it works too, ill mark it as the answered question when the timer's up!

Comment: No problem @TheNuthouse, always glad to help.

Comment: So the calc function knows which two parameters triggered it yes?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through them with `forEach()`. You also have to pass the target the calling function.

```
function calc(target){
  if (target.value.length > 0){
    console.log("hooray");
  };
};

[aV, a].forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
      calc(ev.target);
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function that handles the event should be like this:

```
function calc_keydownHandler(e){
var target = e.target;
//do something with the target now
}
```

Because you've got a argument of target the reference would be target.target which doesn't make sense.